# Get element from WSDL in PHP using Soap

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

i need to make a soap php to get coupons
 from 
https://planetwin365.com/Controls/CouponWS.asmx?wsdl

The WSDL in question is Planetwin365 . The snippet in question looks something like this:

```
    <wsdl:service name="CouponWS">
<wsdl:port name="CouponWSSoap" binding="tns:CouponWSSoap">
<soap:address location="http://planetwin365.com/Controls/CouponWS.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="CouponWSSoap12" binding="tns:CouponWSSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://planetwin365.com/Controls/CouponWS.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I'm currently doing this:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($this->wsdl);
$version = $xml->getElementsByService('CouponWS')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

he didn't work

Comment: first of all `getElementsByService` is not a function of [the `DOMDocument` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and secondly your question is unclear as to what you're trying to get. Are you trying to get the `soap:address location` or what?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I need to create a soap client to get coupon from this wsdl http://www.planetwin365.rs/Controls/CouponWS.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a soap client you do this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://planetwin365.com/Controls/CouponWS.asmx?wsdl");
```

You didn't say exactly which method you wanted to execute.  There is a number of coupon related methods you can choose. You can list them out doing this:

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Which returns a number of operations you can perform:

```
GetSaldoResponse GetSaldo(GetSaldo $parameters)
GetDisbilitazioneGirocontiResponse GetDisbilitazioneGiroconti(GetDisbilitazioneGiroconti $parameters)
GetStatoCouponResponse GetStatoCoupon(GetStatoCoupon $parameters)
CouponPromozioneOKResponse CouponPromozioneOK(CouponPromozioneOK $parameters)
GetStatoCouponAsincronoResponse GetStatoCouponAsincrono(GetStatoCouponAsincrono $parameters)
GetSaldoResponse GetSaldo(GetSaldo $parameters)
GetDisbilitazioneGirocontiResponse GetDisbilitazioneGiroconti(GetDisbilitazioneGiroconti $parameters)
GetStatoCouponResponse GetStatoCoupon(GetStatoCoupon $parameters)
CouponPromozioneOKResponse CouponPromozioneOK(CouponPromozioneOK $parameters)
GetStatoCouponAsincronoResponse GetStatoCouponAsincrono(GetStatoCouponAsincrono $parameters)
```

Choose the one you want to call.  For example, let's take a look at `GetStatoCoupon()`.  We can see that this method takes one parameter called `$parameters` and it is a `GetStatoCoupon` type structure.  The method returns a `GetStatoCouponResponse`.

What does the `GetStatoCoupon` type look like?  To find out do:

```
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

And we can see that GetStatoCoupon looks like:

```
  [4]=>
string(40) "struct GetStatoCoupon {
int IDCoupon;
}"
```

We now have enough information to construct a basic call:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://planetwin365.com/Controls/CouponWS.asmx?wsdl");
$parameters = new StdClass();
$parameters->IDCoupon = 1234;
$response = $client->GetStatoCoupon($parameters);
```

My call results in an error because I don't know what values can go into `IDCoupon`, but hopefully this answers your question on how to create a SOAP client to get coupons.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to php generator to get a SDK/soap client easy to use from [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator)